# Wifi encryption with wicd

Tags: wireless, wicd

I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu to wifi using `wicd`. On access point I have following configuration:

- Security Mode: wpa-wpa2 personal
- Encryption Mode: aes
- WPS Enabled:  No

In `wicd` I have tried following security settings:

```
Wpa 1/2 hex
Wpa-peap
Wpa 1/2 (passphrase)
Wpa2-leap
Wpa2-peap
```

Non of them worked for me. Which one is right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want: `Wpa 1/2 (passphrase)` .

Comment: Saved changes, going to same networking again it's again wpa1/2 hex, even with sudo.

Comment: @holms Please start a new question rather than respond to an old and obsure question from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've had learning curves with WICD in the past along these lines too... My solution was that the router was emitting wpa1/wpa2 but not doing the greatest job of it (for WICD to connect to). I then set the router to wpa2 (passphrase) only (pretty much all tech from the last 5-8 years runs wpa2 in my experience so it doesn't alienate any of my other hardware) and then matched that with wicd...

No problems from there on in...
P.S. your router may have ddifferent options (Labels) to mine but investigate it further and find the matching pair.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

WPA2 Personal corresponds to WPA 1/2 in Wicd.  It is by far the most common in home routers.  WPA2 uses AES so no surprise there.  WPS is just a newer type of setup between compatible routers and wireless cards that basically exchanges very strong passwords automatically for you.  It doesn't matter if you don't have this, just make sure you choose a good password.  You may also want to set your router to only accept connections from known devices.

Usually your router will have a "passphrase" or password configured, so you would want WPA 1/2 (passphrase).  The passphrase for WPA does not have to be printable characters so in the case that your have a non-printable password you would use WPA 1/2 hex and enter a string of unintelligible numbers and a-f letters.

The other WPA2 options are for large corporate type networks, so you might need those at work or possibly at school.

In Wicd you have to select the encryption type and enter the password, *then save*, before you attempt to connect.  If you were correct then you get logged in and the authentication details should be remembered for the future.  Sometimes it takes two or three attempts.